# Mount posixovl using fstab

Tags: fstab, fuse

The following line:

```
/path1  /path2  posixovl    none    0   0
```

fails with the error:

```
/sbin/mount.posixovl: invalid option -- 'o'
Usage: /sbin/mount.posixovl [-F] [-S source] mountpoint [-- fuseoptions]
```

This is because `mount.posixovl` uses a non standard mount syntax, and `fstab` will call it assuming default mount syntax, eg.

```
mount.posixovl /path1 /path2 -o [whatsoever_/etc/fstab_options]
```

**EDIT #1:**
Same problem, solved with an uglier hack in this linuxquestions.org Q&A titled: [[SOLVED] How to get a fuse-posixovl partition mounted at bootup?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-get-a-fuse-posixovl-partition-mounted-at-bootup-4175484792/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a wrapper for `mount.posixovl` that enables it to be used with `fstab`

First, rename `/sbin/mount.posixovl` to something else, like `/sbin/mount.posixovl.orig`

Finally, create a new file `/sbin/mount.posixovl` whith the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
# wrapper for mount.posixovl to conform with common mount syntax
# with this wrapper posixovl can be used in fstab

# location of the original mount.posixovl
origposixovl="/sbin/mount.posixovl.orig"

# gather inputs
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        if [[ "$1" == -* ]]; then
                # var is an input switch
                # we can only use the -o or -F switches
                if [[ "$1" == *F* ]]; then
                        optsF="-F"
                else
                        optsF=""
                fi
                if [[ "$1" == *o* ]]; then
                        shift
                        optsfuse="-- -o $1"
                else
                        optsfuse=""
                fi
                shift
        else
                # var is a main argument
                sourcedir="$1"
                shift
                if [[ "$1" != -* ]]; then
                        targetdir="$1"
                        shift
                else
                        targetdir="$sourcedir"
                fi
        fi
done

# verify inputs
if [ "$sourcedir" == "" ]; then
        echo "no source specified"
        exit 1
fi
if [ "$targetdir" == "" ]; then
        echo "no target specified"
        exit 1
fi

# build mount.posixovl command
"$origposixovl" $optsF -S "$sourcedir" "$targetdir" $optsfuse
```

Naturally, set the newly created `/sbin/mount.posixovl` to be executeable (`chmod +x /sbin/mount.posixovl`)

It is useful mounting `posixovl` trough `fstab`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks vehystrix for sharing your wrapper script. I recently used it to mount a directory inside a users's home. I found two issues I wanted to improve with your script:

1. renaming the original `mont.posixovl` binary means it could brake as soon as the packet manager of your distribution installs a new update
2. the original `mount.posixovl` is always started as root and it seems to ignore `uid=` and `gid=` mount options. This resulted int he filesytem being inaccessible for the user who's home it was mounted to

I slightly changed your script and saved it to `/sbin/mount.fuse-posixovl` instead (which correlates with the ubuntu package name), so i could use a type `fuse-posixovl` in fstab to mount it.

Here is the modified version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# wrapper for mount.posixovl to conform with common mount syntax
# with this wrapper posixovl can be used in fstab
 
# location of the original mount.posixovl
origposixovl="/sbin/mount.posixovl"
 
# gather inputs
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        if [[ "$1" == -* ]]; then
                # var is an input switch
                # we can only use the -o or -F switches
                if [[ "$1" == *F* ]]; then
                        optsF="-F"
                else
                        optsF=""
                fi
                if [[ "$1" == *o* ]]; then
                        shift
                        if [[ "$1" == *uid=* ]]; then
                                runas=$(getent passwd $(echo "$1" | sed -E -e 's/^.*uid=([^,]+)(,.*)?$/\1/') | cut -d: -f1)
                        fi
                        optsfuse="-- -o $1"
                else
                        optsfuse=""
                fi
                shift
        else
                # var is a main argument
                sourcedir="$1"
                shift
                if [[ "$1" != -* ]]; then
                        targetdir="$1"
                        shift
                else
                        targetdir="$sourcedir"
                fi
        fi
done
 
# verify inputs
if [ "$sourcedir" == "" ]; then
        echo "no source specified"
        exit 1
fi
if [ "$targetdir" == "" ]; then
        echo "no target specified"
        exit 1
fi
 
# build mount.posixovl command
if [[ -n "$runas" ]]; then
        su - "${runas}" -c "\"$origposixovl\" $optsF -S \"$sourcedir\" \"$targetdir\" $optsfuse"
else
        "$origposixovl" $optsF -S "$sourcedir" "$targetdir" $optsfuse
fi
```

and here is an example of a fstab line using it:

```
/home/myuser/Nextcloud/homebin            /home/myuser/bin fuse-posixovl   uid=1000,gid=1000    0 0
```